# how to associate a css stylesheet with an svg object reference?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I just learned that there are special css stylesheet constraints when loading an svg as an object reference on a webpage:

https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Storing an svg in it's own separate file provides good separation and maintainability so I'm guessing that the need to associate a css stylesheet with an svg loaded as an object on a webpage is a somewhat common scenario. Can you recommend any good techniques for this?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#StylingWithCSS

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of this explanation, lets say you want to add an image to a "main.html" file.

If you want to keep all of your files separate, a good technique is to save your svg file as an html document (just copy the svg code and save in a new html document), then link the document to your main.html file.  After that, you can either encode the CSS directly to your svg's document or you can style it with a separate style sheet.

Sometimes when I am working with a simple svg file and I'm feeling abundantly lazy, I'll just paste the svg code directly into my main.html document and then style it using my main.css style sheet.

Hope that made sense!